# Minimum cumulative variance to extract in exploratory factor analysis to ensure a good fit

Tags: factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

As a part of my exploratory factor analysis, I would like to report the cumulative variance % (eigenvalues). I wonder if there are guidelines on the minimum percentage in order to have a good model fit? I read somewhere that it should be min. 40% but I cannot seem to find this online anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you are not talking about PCA?

Comment: nope, it's the efa

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by percentage of "cumulative variance" in EFA? How is it computed?

Comment: @amoeba - it's the sum(eigenvalues)/k (where k is the number of variables. If you run, for e.g. fa(matrix(runif(10000), nrow=200), nfactors=3) it's the line that's called cumulative var.

Comment: @Jeremy, thanks, but what eigenvalues? So we take a correlation matrix $C$, choose some number of factors $m$, and perform FA which finds an approximation $C\approx WW^\top + \Psi$, where $W$ are loadings with $m$ columns and $\Psi$ is a diagonal matrix with noise variances ("uniquenesses"). Now, what sum of eigenvalues? Trace of $WW^\top$, so sum of factor variances? Then you normalize by $k$, which is trace of $C$, this I understand.

Comment: Sums of squared rows of W (if you're analyzing a covariance matrix).  Factor variances are (in the way I've always done it) 1. (But that's the identification problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a golden rule.

Deciding on the number of factors is slightly more of an art than a science. Higher proportion of variance is good, but the number of factors and number of variables matters too.

If your scree plot is telling you that you definitely have one factor, and it's only accounted for 25% of the variance, then you should extract only one factor - extract more and you have noise.  The low proportion of variance just means you have crappy measures.

I like to aim for 50% of the variance though.